# Why are these edges appearing in the render?

Tags: modeling, rendering, cycles-render-engine

Is there any easy way to get rid of the visible triangles in the final rendering?
It seems the subdivison in some places is more intense than in others.
Or is the only solution to rebuild the mesh?

[image: Geometry]

[image: Render with visible Distortion]

Comment: It looks like the vertices of the wall are not on the same plane as the door, creating what is called a non planar surface. The topology is fine.

Comment: I also get the impression the vertices are not aligned in the same plane. Try selecting all the vertices and scaling them to 0 in the direction perpendicular to the wall surface.

Comment: thanks, i checked that of course. it is a planar surface.

Comment: In case that all vertices really are on the same plane, you may want to check the ["Face Orientation"](https://imgur.com/MasZWd0), as flipped normals are main culprit to many cases like this.

Comment: face orientation is as is shoud be no flipped normals. thanks for the try.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create loop-cuts from the corners of the doorway horizontally and vertically, so your shape will be essentially 6 'faces' but with the removed doorway.

This SHOULD fix your problem.

One thing you could do is research 'topology' and understand how shapes and vertices work together.

Comment: thank you for your anser. so, in short: there is no fast way. rebuilding the topology is the only solution, it seems?